# What does self.head, self.tail = self.tail, self.head do in a doubly linked list?

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I'm asked what the effect of `self.head, self.tail = self.tail, self.head` is on a doubly linked list.

If I implement this code, **the list now only consists of the last item added.**

```
# Represent a node of doubly linked list
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data;
        self.previous = None;
        self.next = None;


class DoublyLinkedList:
    # Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None;
        self.tail = None;

        # addNode() will add a node to the list

    def addNode(self, data):
        # Create a new node
        newNode = Node(data);

        # If list is empty
        if (self.head == None):
            # Both head and tail will point to newNode
            self.head = self.tail = newNode;
            # head's previous will point to None
            self.head.previous = None;
            # tail's next will point to None, as it is the last node of the list
            self.tail.next = None;
        else:
            # newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next will point to newNode
            self.tail.next = newNode;
            # newNode's previous will point to tail
            newNode.previous = self.tail;
            # newNode will become new tail
            self.tail = newNode;
            # As it is last node, tail's next will point to None
            self.tail.next = None;

            # display() will print out the nodes of the list

    def display(self):
        # Node current will point to head
        current = self.head;
        if (self.head == None):
            print("List is empty");
            return;
        print("Nodes of doubly linked list: ");
        while (current != None):
            # Prints each node by incrementing pointer.
            print(current.data),;
            current = current.next;

    def weird_line(self):
        self.head, self.tail = self.tail, self.head


dList = DoublyLinkedList();
# Add nodes to the list
dList.addNode(1);
dList.addNode(2);
dList.addNode(3);
dList.addNode(4);
dList.addNode(5);

dList.weird_line();

dList.display();
```

OUTPUT: 5

source: https://www.javatpoint.com/python-program-to-create-and-display-a-doubly-linked-list

However, my professor is letting me choose out of four options:

1. The list will show up in reverse.
2. The list will be empty
3. The second half of the list will be deleted
4. The first half of the list will be deleted

I'm pretty sure, that my initial answer is correct.
Is there someone that could argue that one of the possible answers he gave me could be correct?

Comment: You don't need semicolons after every line, and adding them is not a good idea. Indeed, one of them obscures a rogue comma that would cause a bug if it happened to be on a different line.

Comment: In fact, the whole implementation that website gives is poor.

Comment: The source you refer to has no mention of this swap. Do you have a source for that?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have presented, you are right that the final `display` call will print the value of the node that was last added.

None of the four given options is true.

We can make some other remarks:

This swap of `head` and `tail` will make the list inconsistent, as you would expect the following to be always true:

- `head` or `head.previous` is `None`
- `tail` or `tail.next` is `None`
- In a non-emtpy list, if you start with the `head` node, and follow the `next` references until a node's `next` attribute is `None`, you'll end up at the `tail` node.
- In a non-emtpy list, if you start with the `tail` node, and follow the `previous` references until a node's `previous` attribute is `None`, you'll end up at the `head` node.

All these invariants will be violated if you call `weird_line` on a list with at least 2 nodes.

Comment: Any feed-back on this answer?